# Launching classes from onCreate and calling methods from parent classes in sub classes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to design an android game which has multiple game modes. These game modes are represented by different classes and which class is to be used should be decided on startup, with the defaut being say Class A. Changing settings will prompt the game to start using Class B.

The thing is, because there is quite some shared functionality between the two classes, I have a super class containing the common functionality, so that I in theory would be able to call the methods from the subclasses. However, I can't get this to work.

EDIT: I've figured out why the methods didn't work, as they did all along, but since I'm bypassing onCreate of the parent class for now, the data used in the methods was not loaded. Stupid mistake, fixed that.
I'm still not able to use onCreate to decide which subclass to use though.

This is basically how I'm trying to implement all of this (I did not display Class B as its irrelevant for now):

```
public Class Parent{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);

        chooseMode();
    }

    private void chooseMode(){
        if (conditionA){
            Intent modeA = new Intent(this, A.class);
            startActivity(modeA);
        }

        else{
            Intent modeB = new Intent(this, B.class);
            startActivity(modeB)
        }

}

    protected void display_imgView(){
        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}



public Class A extends Parent{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);

    }

    public void someMethod(){
        super.display_imgView();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Intents are used to start Activities, Services or Broadcasts. I'm going to assume your classes are meant to be Activities. In that case the **Parent** class should be extending **Activity**.

For what you are trying to do, you may want to consider the Strategy pattern. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java

Comment: I've tried that before, but that didn't work either. However, I've opted to try out strategy patterning and this is very useful indeed.

The only thing I'm currently confused about is why my imageViews are not found when executing an alternative strategy, but they are when using the regular one.

Comment: Are you getting a warning on your `onCreate(...)` function? You must extend activity otherwise `onCreate(...)` won't execute at all. Maybe that's where you're calling your **findViewById**s ?